# Testing for NaN in a JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, highcharts

Yesterday I posted a question about getting highcharts.JS to handle an issue when XML data was pushed to it. I didn't go very in depth so I think the answer I got was a bit off so I am going to try and re-post it today and see if I can get an answer more suited to my issue

I have a Quickbase application that is being graphed to a highchart.js graph using XML data from an API call. The XML data is a table query bringing back record data from 14 fields. In those fields the data can range from .001 to 99.99, HOWEVER some of them will be blank from time to time producing an array of {NaN,NaN,NaN}, When that series is pushed into the graph it makes the whole graph blank until you de-select that option

It was suggested yesterday that Highcharts has a built in "nodata" function, however the only way I could find it explained was when there was an instance that there was absolutely no data being provided to the graph (in which case it showed on the graph "No Data", but that is not what I am looking for as there will always be at least one (usually at least five, but for simplicity sake I will say one) field having data.

Here is the code I am currently using

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Graph</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var sgaxml = 'https://sga.quickbase.com/db/bjmdensiu?apptoken=beadyrucxguavbx5isubd6iaqpe&act=API_DoQuery&query=%7B14.EX.%27_FID_9%7D&clist=7.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.31.32.33.34.35.36.37'

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Components Over Time'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Concentration%'
                }
            },
            series: []
        };

        // Load the data from the XML file 
        $.get(sgaxml, function(xml) {

        // Split the lines
        var xml = $(xml).find('record');


    // Variables for the component series

    var seriesH = {
            name: 'Hydrogen',
            data: []
        };

         var seriesHe = {
            name: 'Helium',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesO = {
            name: 'Oxygen',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesHs = {
            name: 'Hydrogen Sulfide',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesN = {
            name: 'Nitrogen',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesC = {
            name: 'Carbon Dioxide',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesM = {
            name: 'Methane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesE = {
            name: 'Ethane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesP = {
            name: 'Propane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesIb = {
            name: 'Iso-Butane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesNb = {
            name: 'N-Butane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesIp = {
            name: 'Iso-Pentane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesNp = {
            name: 'N-Pentane',
            data: []
        };

    var seriesHex = {
            name: 'Hexanes+',
            data: []
        };

    xml.each(function (i, record) {
            options.xAxis.categories.push(new Date(parseInt($(record).find('sample_date').text())));
        seriesH.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('hydrogen').text()));
        seriesHe.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('helium').text()));
        seriesO.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('oxygen').text()));
        seriesHs.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('hydrogen_sulfide').text()));
        seriesN.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('nitrogen').text()));
        seriesC.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('co2').text()));
            seriesM.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('methane').text()));
            seriesE.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('ethane').text()));
        seriesP.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('propane').text()));
        seriesIb.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('iso_butane').text()));
        seriesNb.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('n_butane').text()));
        seriesIp.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('iso_pentane').text()));
        seriesNp.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('n_pentane').text()));
        seriesHex.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('hexanes_').text()));
        });

    console.log(seriesO.data);  

        if(seriesH.data >= .001){console.log("No Hydrogen Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesH)};
    if(seriesHe.data >= .001){console.log("No Helium Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesHe)};
    if(seriesO.data >= .001){console.log("No Oxygen Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesO)};
    if(seriesHs.data >= .001){console.log("No H2S Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesHs)};
    if(seriesN.data >= .001){console.log("No Nitrogen Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesN)};
    if(seriesC.data >= .001){console.log("No Carbon Dioxide Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesC)};
    if(seriesM.data >= .001){console.log("No Methane Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesM)};
    if(seriesE.data >= .001){console.log("No Ethane Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesE)};
    if(seriesP.data >= .001){console.log("No Propane Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesP)};
    if(seriesIb.data >= .001){console.log("No Iso-B Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesIb)};
    if(seriesNb.data >= .001){console.log("No N-B Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesNb)};
    if(seriesIp.data >= .001){console.log("No Iso-P Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesIp)};
    if(seriesNp.data >=.001){console.log("No N-P Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesNp)};
    if(seriesHex.data >=.001){console.log("No Hexane+ Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesHex)};
        console.log('options: ', options);

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style=" width: 1000px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the XML output from the API call

```
    <qdbapi>
<action>API_DoQuery</action>
<errcode>0</errcode>
<errtext>No error</errtext>
<dbinfo>
<name>RESULT</name>
<desc/>
</dbinfo>
<variables>
<co2>Carbon Dioxide</co2>
<methane>methane</methane>
</variables>
<chdbids></chdbids>
<record>
<sample_date>1386892800000</sample_date>
<hydrogen>0.002</hydrogen>
<helium>0.114</helium>
<oxygen/>
<hydrogen_sulfide/>
<nitrogen>1.926</nitrogen>
<co2>0.454</co2>
<methane>82.163</methane>
<ethane>6.353</ethane>
<propane>4.760</propane>
<iso_butane>0.618</iso_butane>
<n_butane>1.819</n_butane>
<iso_pentane>0.491</iso_pentane>
<n_pentane>0.544</n_pentane>
<hexanes_>0.756</hexanes_>
<update_id>1408654196361</update_id>
</record>
<record>
<sample_date>1383782400000</sample_date>
<hydrogen>0.006</hydrogen>
<helium>0.038</helium>
<oxygen/>
<hydrogen_sulfide/>
<nitrogen>0.512</nitrogen>
<co2>0.844</co2>
<methane>83.178</methane>
<ethane>8.678</ethane>
<propane>3.631</propane>
<iso_butane>0.493</iso_butane>
<n_butane>1.097</n_butane>
<iso_pentane>0.342</iso_pentane>
<n_pentane>0.371</n_pentane>
<hexanes_>0.810</hexanes_>
<update_id>1408981434690</update_id>
</record>
<record>
<sample_date>1369699200000</sample_date>
<hydrogen>0.004</hydrogen>
<helium>0.060</helium>
<oxygen/>
<hydrogen_sulfide/>
<nitrogen>1.684</nitrogen>
<co2>0.443</co2>
<methane>77.742</methane>
<ethane>10.430</ethane>
<propane>6.842</propane>
<iso_butane>0.587</iso_butane>
<n_butane>1.482</n_butane>
<iso_pentane>0.232</iso_pentane>
<n_pentane>0.249</n_pentane>
<hexanes_>0.245</hexanes_>
<update_id>1408981112624</update_id>
</record>
</qdbapi>
```

I know that in the last half of my code that the if else isn't going to work because the value in the array isn't a number and is instead NaN. My question is how exactly would I go about testing if I have the value NaN, and if I do, don't push that series to the graph. I can't just cut it out completely as some will in fact have values for the ones currently getting values on NaN

Comment: `$.isNumeric()`??? Aren't you able to provide only minimalistic relevant code instead of all this bunch of unreadable code?

Comment: I may be a tad confused, but what do you mean by sum-an...?

Comment: AH! isNumeric did work, for some reason last time I tried to use it I didn't think about needing to change my if else to where the true was the push.....Wow.....Sorry guys! Thanks Wolf!!      Also the last time I only posted the "relevant code" I was told I didn't include everything needed sorry for the overkill.

Comment: @ALearningExperince I mean to say in summary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your xml, the values are valid numbers so it cant be NaN.
One logic error I found in your code is, you are comparing an array `seriesH.data` with a number `.001` which is not valid.

```
 if(seriesH.data >= .001){console.log("No Hydrogen Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesH)};
```

you should rather compare individual element of array against the numeric value test.

```
 if(seriesH.data[0] >= .001){console.log("No Hydrogen Data")} else {options.series.push(seriesH)};
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense too, I didn't think about the fact I was trying to compare an array to a number so good call on that.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason your array is counted as NaN against the comparison.